# Magento 2.3.0 MSI isTableExists calls take too long

Tags: magento2.3, performance, msi

I'm experiencing slow performance coming from MSI.
New Relic reports something like:
48 runs of `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ?` that takes in total 5 seconds.
There are many calls to this because it's about a configurable product in cart that has many associated simple products. Or it's just big cart with many products.

The issue starts like this:

```
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\QuantityValidatorObserver::execute
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator\Initializer\StockItem::initialize()
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry\Interceptor::getStockStatus()
\Magento\InventoryCatalog\Plugin\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistry\AdaptGetStockStatusPlugin::afterGetStockStatus()
\Magento\InventorySales\Model\GetProductSalableQty::execute()
\Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\ResourceModel\GetStockItemData::execute()
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::isTableExists()
\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::showTableStatus()
```

The URL for above trace is from `customer/section/load/`.
But I see same issue in other URLs.

- How can I optimize this with code in Magento 2 (not server/software optimization) ?
- Does `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ?` MySQL locks on table `inventory_stock_123` ?
- `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ?` is executed on table(s) `inventory_stock_123`, correct ? Yes.
- Is there a Magento 2 / MSI patch for this ?

EDIT:

- The store uses 10.0.38-MariaDB
- I believe the big times happen when there are race conditions on the server. This should happen when there locks in progress on table `inventory_stock_123`.
- I replaced all calls (five) in inventory modules from `if ($connection->isTableExists($tableName)` to:

```
try {
    $connection->query('SELECT 1 FROM ' . $tableName . ' LIMIT 1');
    $exists = true;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $exists = false;
}
if ($exists) {
  ..
```

I can't say that this is the best way to do it but I got very good results. There are other SQL queries to check if a table exists.
3 of the call `isTableExists` were impacting frontend experience. And 2 of them were making admin product save very slow.

**Update:**

It's a server issue / webstack configuration. It has something to do with the storage for MySql data.

Comment: Do you want to use Multi Source Inventory (MSI)?

Comment: @DominicXigen The store uses MSI and running.`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ?` adds a bunch of seconds on page load first byte.

Comment: What I'm getting at is do you actually want to use the feature though?  As in does the store require a multi-source inventory or does it only have a single source inventory?

Comment: @DominicXigen I am already using the feature. It's on a multistore with 2 stock sources (2 warehouses) and 2 stocks. One stock source for a stock (one to one relation). I got the PHP trace from New Relic calling MSI code (`magento/module-inventory*`). 'Default' stock is not assigned to products according to Admin > Stores > Stocks > Sales Channel is empty for Default Stock.

Comment: @DominicXigen MSI is not Multi-Source feature for Magento, it's a new inventory mechanism. Just consider that in one of the upcoming releases CatalogInventory would be fully eliminated from the codebase.

Comment: The point I was getting to is that if it's not something you use you could try and remove it https://www.integer-net.com/make-magento-2-small-again/

Comment: @DominicXigen I didn't know I can do that. It's a great suggestion to disable modules. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen any similar reports so far, so created a new ticket for MSI: https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/issues/2282 to track investigation and possibly fix.

Do you use Magento 2.3.0 with MSI 1.0.*? Some performance issues could have been fixed in 1.1.1 and even more fixed in upcoming 1.1.2.

Comment: I have the latest code of MSI from 1.1.1. I use Magento 2.3.0. The store has the same version of `module-inventory*` with the inventory modules shipped with Magento 2.3.1. I guess MSI it's build like this. If you run `composer update` (without changing [magento installation]/composer.json) or maybe just `composer install` than it will bring latest compatible MSI code.

Comment: @obscure Thanks for clarification.This would definitely help. Can you also share more information on the specific table which causes the issue? Existing table `inventory_stock_1` is not an actual table but a VIEW, while all other numbers are actual tables. Would be nice to figure out if this is something view-specific.

Comment: It's about inventory_stock_3. This is the table for the stock that has associated to it only one source. Beside this I saw that `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'setup_module'` can take up to 300ms (executed once in `\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleResource::_loadVersion`). We're investigating if this is a MariaDb 10.0.38 bug, miss configuration or something else server related. Or just if there is something coming from code in Magento that could overload the database server.

Comment: It's a server issue. I updated my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Following code was released by Magento to fix the show status calls:

https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/inventory/pull/2350.patch
https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/inventory/pull/2336.patch
The patches are intended to reduce the calls to the inventory_stock_1

1.https://github.com/magento/inventory/commit/ad57569792551b58d22e169ed536da4ac22a0f2d [Added Caching to Services]
2. https://github.com/magento/inventory/pull/2561

Answer (score 0):

Decided to put as potential answer rather that comment which can be easily missed. I realise it may not solve your issue but it could be helpful for someone.

It is possible to streamline magento. The guys that did it have seen up to 40% increase in performance. Anyway it may be a potential option for anyone not making full use of MSI in the way in which the magento team intended.

https://www.integer-net.com/make-magento-2-small-again/

Add this to composer.json

```
    "replace": {
        "magento/module-dhl": "*",
        "magento/module-fedex": "*",
        "magento/module-marketplace": "*",
        "magento/module-multishipping": "*",
        "magento/module-captcha": "*",
        "magento/module-persistent": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "*",
        "magento/module-authorizenet": "*",
        "magento/module-google-adwords": "*",
        "magento/module-sample-data": "*",
        "magento/module-send-friend": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi": "*",
        "magento/module-swagger-webapi-async": "*",
        "magento/module-swatches": "*",
        "magento/module-swatches-layered-navigation": "*",
        "magento/module-google-optimizer": "*",
        "magento/module-ups": "*",
        "magento/module-usps": "*",
        "magento/module-braintree": "*",
        "magento/module-signifyd": "*",
        "magento/module-release-notification": "*",
        "magento/module-new-relic-reporting": "*",
        "magento/module-version": "*",

        "magento/module-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-quote-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-review-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-sales-analytics": "*",
        "magento/module-wishlist-analytics": "*",

        "magento/module-bundle-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-cms-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-cms-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-configurable-product-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-eav-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-grouped-product-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-quote-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-store-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-swatches-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-tax-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-url-rewrite-graph-ql": "*",
        "magento/module-weee-graph-ql": "*",

        "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-configurable-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-customer-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-downloadable-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-grouped-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-tax-import-export": "*",

        "magento/module-inventory": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-cache": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-catalog-search": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-indexer": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configuration": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",

        "magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-indexer": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-import-export": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-indexer": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-multi-dimensional-indexer-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-product-alert": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-reservations": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-reservations-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-sales-frontend-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-shipping": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-source-selection": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*",
        "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection": "*",
        "temando/module-shipping-m2": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
        "klarna/module-kp": "*",
        "klarna/module-ordermanagement": "*",
        "klarna/module-core": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "*",
        "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "*",
        "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "*",
        "vertex/module-tax": "*",
        "vertex/sdk": "*"
    },
```

Comment: While this solution may be functional, in case with `Inventory*` modules, it should be noted that at some point in the future it will replace the existing `CatalogInventory` module, possibly creating an additional challenge in upgrades.

Comment: Agreed however for those who still want to explore this route cleaner alternative https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292227/70343