# Magento 2.3 cleanest way to remove MSI to speed up store

Tags: magento2.3, performance, msi

My question is simple.  What is the cleanest way to speed up Magento 2.3.x by removing MSI.

In my opinion this is a B2B feature and most small merchants won't be interested in this feature. IMHO it is adding MySQL overhead.

Has anyone had any success disabling this without causing issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that the best idea to remove the package using composer, use composer replace tag for removing the MSI modules.

Create **a custom module on this module's composer.json remove**  the MSI module like this ways

```
{
  "name": "vendor/magento2-replace-inventory",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "replace": {
    "magento/module-inventory": "*",
    .....
```

**OR** You can use `Jisse Reitsma` module https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory for this purpose.

If you already install & enable ALL MSI modules, then first you have disabled them one by one using `php bin/magento module: disable {VendorName}_{ModuleName}`,

Then remove the package using composer

Comment: That's a great solution.  Have you used this yourself.

Comment: I never use myself. But you can Trust `Jisse Reitsma` :) he is  Magento Master :)

Comment: Never trust anyone by default @DominicXigen

Comment: @vitoriodachef   why you donot trust anyonne?

Comment: @AmitBera trust but verify :)

Comment: Don't trust me! I know best!

Comment: @JisseReitsma, always believe you:)

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend to rather apply performance patches which address all the known performance problems with MSI than disable it. 
The list of patches could be found here - https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Performance-Patches.

Magento 2.3.3 with MSI + 2 additional patches shows better checkout performance than the one without MSI.

Comment: I can appreciate the suggestion. It is safer. However I think MSI should have been optional install like sample data. M2 is very heavy db application. Just turn off cache or manage a large catalog and you will see. To add further db load to checkout and basket makes me uncomfortable. Even with these modifications add 20 items in your basket see what performance you get.

Comment: I'm not critical of MSI as a feature. I've looked through the code and it is a feat of engineering. I do however think it has limited applications. For me personally I'd say 1 in every 20 sites I'm responsible for want this feature

Comment: That’s exactly my point. MSI is not a stand-alone feature whuch could be considered separately of Magento. This is a new Inventory mechanism of Magento, btw it has already been renamed to Magento inventory because of this. Moreover since Magento 2.5 it would be the only option as CatalogInventory would be removed

Comment: Are you able to explain how to apply these patches https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294378/magento-2-3-upgrade-magento-inventory-msi