# MAGENTO 2: HOW TO DISABLE MSI in MAGENTO 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, inventory, msi, multi-source-inventory

How one can disable the MSI module in Magento 2.3.0 if not in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the magento developers want to know how to disable the MSI inventory module from there setup. Please note that the MSI module is newly introduced since version 2.3.0. One can read the below article on it.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/inventory/

But today lets see how to disable this inventory module in Magento version 2.3.0. This can be done in the following ways:

**NOTE : The modules are listed on the magento site  https://devdocs.magento.com/extensions/inventory-management/ . The MSI modules may differ in the different versions of magento2.3. X. Hence before directly implementing the below solution I will request you to cross verify the modules in the app/etc/config.php file of your project with given link and than proceed further. I have disabled the modules according to magento version 2.3.0**

1. Using Magento2 module disable command.

`php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi`

2. By replacing value to '0' in the following modules in the app/etc/config.php file.

```
Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryAdminUi
Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalog
Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryConfiguration
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryImportExport
Magento_InventoryCache
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryProductAlert
Magento_InventoryReservations
Magento_InventoryReservationCli
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventoryExportStock
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGraphQl
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi
Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
Magento_InventoryShipping
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelection
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
```

Once you finish doing the above thing please do not forget to run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I very much appreciated your excellent work! Keep up the good work! :)

Comment: Thanks @YoYoRoshan

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use composer

This is potentially the cleaner option as you are no longer loading the code

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292227/70343

https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory

```
{
  "name": "yireo/magento2-replace-inventory",
  "version": "2.3.3",
  "replace": {
    "magento/module-inventory": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-advanced-checkout": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-requisition-list": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-cache": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-search": "*",
    "magento/inventory-composer-installer": "*",
    "magento/inventory-composer-metapackage": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configuration": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-export-stock": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-export-stock-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-multi-dimensional-indexer-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-product-alert": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservations": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservations-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-frontend-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-setup-fixture-generator": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-shipping": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-selection": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*",
    "magento/module-sales-inventory": "*"
  }
}
```