# Disable modules versus remove them

Tags: magento2

I have some modules that I'm not going to use. E.g Temando_Shipping, MSI modules, GraghQl modules,...

Should I disable them using config.php or should I remove them from the codebase using composer replace?

Which one is the better approach and has a better performance result?

Comment: Better performance is to remove https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-all but you will have issues to work though every time you add or remove extension or upgrade core.

Comment: Give it a try on a test vanilla store with sample data https://github.com/DominicWatts/Benchmark

Comment: Biggest issue for me was MSI. Early versions of MSI really slowed down some stores in dev https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292214/magento-2-3-cleanest-way-to-remove-msi-to-speed-up-store fortunately recent upgrades / patches have fixed some of the issues

Comment: @DominicXigen Thanks, I've used this package https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory before. I'm just wondering how fast it is comparing to disabling the modules, thoughts?

Comment: Using that benchmark script I got about 30% improvement on a demo store on saving products. But I implemented on an actual project and as soon as I started adding third party extensions I had problems. But I saw about a 20% improvement on applying MSI upgrade which included their patches. The amazon payment modules stood out for adding noticable load but I could never figure out why.

Comment: Sorry just realised what you meant. I always removed. I didnt disable. I didn't want any unused code still be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks for the removing vote.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Unused modules is the best approach and it has good performance result. Removing them completely from code base may have unintended side effects.

Comment: Thanks. How do you compare the performance between disabling the modules vs removing them?